# Disable mailto from email in GMail Body

Tags: html, hyperlink, gmail, href, mailto

I send mails to gmail users through google smtp.
We use email addresses as their Login Ids.
When I send their email addresses in mail body, the address is shown with mail to.
Example, I intend to show : test@test.com [as plain Text]
But what they get is HTML :

```
<a href="mailto:test@test.com" target="_blank">test@test.com</a>
```

Somewhere on SO, I read that replacing '@' and '.' with their hex codes would fix the issue, but it didn't.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I hacked it by adding my CSS/html to the email address where I specified the mailto as empty and removed the link decoration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hacked it by adding my CSS/html to the email address where I specified the mailto as empty and removed the link decoration.